# Comparing if an element in a dictionary is greater than a variable

Tags: python

I am new to Python and have just recently learnt what dictionaries are and was experimenting with some code.

```
import random
random_number= random.randint(0,100)
print(random_number)

scores = {89: 'Grade 9', 79: 'Grade 8', 69: 'Grade 7', 59: 'Grade 6', 49: 'Grade 5', 39: 'Grade 4', 29: 'Grade 3','Grade 2': 19,'Grade 1': 9,}

def if_random_number(score):
    if random_number > scores[]:
        print('\nYou are grade {}'.format(score, scores.get(item, 'invalid')))
```

I am trying to make it compare if the `random_number` is greater than the elements in the list `scores` it, will print out your grade.
Since I'm new to coding and honestly suck I need some help

Comment: To be clear, `scores` is a `dict` not a `list`.

Comment: You should use a for-loop to compare the random number with each key in the dictionary. You should also work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: alright thank u can u help on how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rework of your code that I think does what you're looking for:

```
import random
random_number= random.randint(0,100)

scores = {89: 'Grade 9', 79: 'Grade 8', 69: 'Grade 7', 59: 'Grade 6', 49: 'Grade 5', 39: 'Grade 4', 29: 'Grade 3', 19: 'Grade 2',  9: 'Grade 1'}

def if_random_number(random_score):
    for score, grade in scores.items():
        if random_score >= score:
            print('\nYour score of {} is grade {}'.format(score, grade))
            break
    else:
        print('\nYou suck')

if_random_number(random_number)
```

Sample results:

```
Your score of 9 is grade Grade 1

Your score of 79 is grade Grade 8
```

You iterate over your 'scores' dictionary looking for the first entry where the key (the score) is less than the random number you computed.  The `else` clause is a more advanced trick where you can do something if in a `for` loop, your test never succeeded and so you never called `break` to break out of the loop.  Since your random number can be less than all keys in `scores` (can be < 9), you need this `else` clause to be sure that you always print something.

Answer (score -1):

In `Python` you can iterate over `dict`s this way:

```
for key, value in dictionary.items():
    # Here you have the keys as key and values as value
```

In your case:

```
for score in scores.keys():
    if (score >= random_number):
        print(scores[score])
```

or otherwise

```
for score, mark in scores.items():
    if (score >= random_number):
        print(mark)
```

---

You can also do it with list comprehension:

```
[print(value) for key, value in scores.items() if key >= random_number]
```

Comment: The downvote is because your code A) doesn't provide a full answer to the question, and B) if plugged into the OP's code, will produce the wrong result.  Did you try your code?  Try it.  You won't get a good result.